# dpkg -i my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64.deb fails with "unable to make backup link of './boot/Image' before installing new version: Operation not..."

Tags: linux-kernel, deb, arm64, vfat

I've made my own kernel package for a custom iMX8M board, which passes lintian without warnings or errors.

The top three layers of the package tree are:

```
/tmp/my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64
|-- DEBIAN
|   |-- control
|   `-- preinst
|-- boot
|   |-- Image
|   `-- dtbs
|       `-- imx8mq-smarc.dtb
|-- lib
|   `-- modules
`-- usr
    `-- share
        `-- doc
```

preinst makes sure that /boot is mounted:

```
fadedbee@box ~ $ sudo cat /tmp/my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64/DEBIAN/preinst 
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if grep -qs '/dev/mmcblk1p1 /boot' /proc/mounts; then
  echo "/boot is mounted."
else
  echo "/boot is not yet mounted, mounting..."
  mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /boot
fi
exit 0
```

It mounts /boot, if not already mounted and relies on the dpkg to put all of the files in place.

It currently fails.

```
root@arm:~# dpkg -i /tmp/my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64.deb 
(Reading database ... 45956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64.deb ...
/boot is not yet mounted, mounting...
Unpacking my-kernel (5.10.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64.deb (--install):
 unable to make backup link of './boot/Image' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/my-kernel_5.10.9-2lEIW6BD_arm64.deb
```

The permissions on /boot/Image are as expected:

```
root@arm:~# ls -lsa /boot/Image
28680 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29366784 Mar 25 11:48 /boot/Image
```

The /boot partition is vfat and mounted R/W:

```
root@arm:~# mount | grep boot
/dev/mmcblk1p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Why might this operation be failing?

Is there a work-around?

---

Update: I've checked what's inside a "normal" debian kernel package.  It also relies on normal behaviour to install the kernel image in /boot.

```
root@debian:/tmp/tmp# tree -L 3
.
├── boot
│   ├── config-6.1.0-18-amd64
│   ├── System.map-6.1.0-18-amd64
│   └── vmlinuz-6.1.0-18-amd64
├── lib
│   └── modules
│       └── 6.1.0-18-amd64
└── usr
    └── share
        ├── bug
        ├── doc
        └── lintian

10 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: I've been helped to see that "link" is the critical word.  FAT filesystems may not support symbolic and/or hard links.  I will try using ext2 for boot instead of FAT.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to fix two problems to make this work.

1. I amended my disk-image build system to create a ext4 /boot instead of the vendor-provided vfat /boot.  This allows dpkg to make symlinks and hardlinks.  Unfortunately this led to u-boot failing to load uEnv.txt, the kernel Image and the device-tree blob.  I was able to use the u-boot monitor to list the files on /boot, so I was confused for an hour or two, until I did a "print env" and noticed that there were some "loadfat" calls in the compiled-in environment.

```
u-boot$ ext4ls mmc 1:1
<DIR>       1024 .
<DIR>       1024 ..
<DIR>      12288 lost+found
<DIR>       1024 dtbs
        29366784 Image
            1163 uEnv.txt

u-boot$ printenv
...
loadaddr=0x40480000
loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} uEnv.txt
loadbootscript=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${script};
loadfdt=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdt_addr} /dtbs/${fdt_file}
loadimage=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${image}
...
```

2. To fix that, I first confirmed that I could manually fix the environment and boot from ext4.  Then I found the correct source file and edited u-boot's smarcimx8mq.h:

```
fadedbee@box ~/my_build/src/uboot $ git diff
diff --git a/include/configs/smarcimx8mq.h b/include/configs/smarcimx8mq.h
index 7eb93677cd..43ce2636eb 100644
--- a/include/configs/smarcimx8mq.h
+++ b/include/configs/smarcimx8mq.h
@@ -101,8 +101,8 @@
        "mmcroot=" CONFIG_MMCROOT " rootwait rw\0" \
        "usbroot=/dev/sda2 rootwait ro\0" \
                "mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait\0" \
-               "loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} uEnv.txt\0" \
+               "loadbootenv=ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} uEnv.txt\0" \
                "loadusbbootenv=fatload usb 0:1 ${loadaddr} uEnv.txt\0" \
        "mmcautodetect=yes\0" \
                        "importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc (uEnv.txt)...; " \
                                "env import -t $loadaddr $filesize\0" \
@@ -112,13 +112,13 @@
                        "rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} root=${mmcroot}\0 " \
                        "usbargs=setenv bootargs ${jh_clk} console=${console} ${optargs} " \
                        "rootfsusbtype=${usbrootfstype} root=${usbroot}\0 " \
-       "loadbootscript=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${script};\0" \
+       "loadbootscript=ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${script};\0" \
        "bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc ...; " \
                "source\0" \
-       "loadimage=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${image}\0" \
+       "loadimage=ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${image}\0" \
         "loadm4bin=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${m4_addr_tmp} ${m4_bin}\0" \
                "loadusbimage=fatload usb 0:1 ${loadaddr} ${image}\0" \
-               "loadfdt=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdt_addr} /dtbs/${fdt_file}\0" \
+               "loadfdt=ext4load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdt_addr} /dtbs/${fdt_file}\0" \
                "loadusbfdt=fatload usb 0:1 ${fdt_addr} /dtbs/${fdt_file}\0" \
         "cpm4mem=cp.b ${m4_addr_tmp} ${m4_addr} 20000\0" \
        "mmcboot=echo Booting from mmc ...; " \
```

and recompiled u-boot.